# Rename "Primarily Opinion Based"

Tags: discussion, feature-request

With the current vibe that questions quality is rapidly decreasing and closing needs to be faster and easier, one *crucial component* is being overlooked.

#### The problem with "Primarily Opinion Based"

I like *Primarily Opinion Based*. Unfortunately, there are a lot of ways that the phrasing encourages it to get misused. Here are some from a *quick* run of the close votes queue.

1. "*Primarily Opinion Based*" despite having objective answers

   - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24144433/background-image-for-table-columns-several-or-a-way-to-do-it-in-css-tables
   - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145996/visual-studio-dependencies
   - [Save a certain segment of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24146259/save-a-certain-segment-of-a-string)
   - [Data Encoding and Decoding while exporting and importing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136651/data-encoding-and-decoding-while-exporting-and-importing)
2. "*Primarily Opinion Based*" for *daring* to ask about *what* something is

   - [what are the purpose of different types of assembly registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130930/what-are-the-purpose-of-different-types-of-assembly-registers)
   - [What is thread hopping and when is it necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24125470/what-is-thread-hopping-and-when-is-it-necessary)
3. Because... I *really* don't know

   - [Xcode 6 beta - Null error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24141123/xcode-6-beta-null-error)
   - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22929409/backward-compatibility-with-template-toolkit-xslate

Further, there are useful questions with objective answers which are disallowed by this close reason, such as "[When should I separately implement IEnumerator<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24142614/when-should-i-separately-implement-ienumeratort)"

#### The solution

By rephrasing the title, we could make it clear that the close reason doesn't apply to questions that just *involve* opinion, but questions *looking for* opinion.

If we close all questions that *involve* opinion, we pretty much close all questions with multiple answers. The problems come when we have questions where there is no matter of expertise. Where there *is no right answer*.

This is not what is getting across to reviewers. **If you don't believe me, go through the "*Primarily Opinion Based*" filter for a short time.** It's disturbing how eager people are to close good, helpful and high-quality questions.

If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946662/why-shouldnt-i-use-pypy-over-cpython-if-pypy-is-6-3-times-faster) is somehow worthy of staying open, there's [no reason for this to have four close votes as if it were asking about a matter of opinion on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116662/differences-when-writing-code-for-arm-vs-x86).

Comment: Side comment: should I tag this with [close-reasons](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/close-reasons)?

Comment: This used to be called "too subjective". There must've been a good reason it was changed.

Comment: Only *one* of the questions you're providing as examples of improper closure is actually closed.  The rest are *all* open.  Before claiming examples abuse of the system, you should find cases where the system is actually being abused...

Comment: *despite having objective answers* -- not really relevant.

Comment: @Servy The reason all of those are still open is because I got them just now from the review queue. The reason I looked is because I've seen too many questions attacked on this reason inappropriately. No other close reason has such a high proportion of inappropriate votes, as far as I've seen.

Comment: The first two questions you cited are "unclear what you are asking," and should be closed anyway.  Several of your other examples never attracted enough close votes to close... Why are you worrying about questions that never closed?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I do agree that some of these *should* be closed, but I wish them to be closed for the right reason. [See also my response to Servy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260088/rename-primarily-opinion-based?noredirect=1#comment40237_260088).

Comment: I've already taken care of that.

Comment: Anyway, this is the reason it takes five votes to close a question.

Comment: @Veedrac The system is specifically designed to deal with a certain amount of improper votes.  That's why it takes 5.  Unless these questions are actually getting closed when they shouldn't be, the system is working properly.

Comment: The [question tagged with arm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116662/differences-when-writing-code-for-arm-vs-x86) is asking about both *python* and 'C'.  I can assure you there are a plethora of opinions on how to change your 'C' code to be more ARM friendly.  And every one will have pluses and minuses; at one point, there was *book like* as a close reason.  If the poster restricted to *python* alone, it might make sense.

Comment: @artlessnoise The question isn't "how do I best make code ARM friendly?" but "do I need to make code ARM friendly?" It's like the difference between "is it possible to solve this equation?" and "what's the best way of solving this equation?" Only one is an opinion.

Comment: The question then is *How do I write portable code*?  That makes it *too broad*; but there can certainly be varying opinions on how to write portable code.

Comment: While this may not be a problem with reasons like "too broad" and "primarily opinion-based" for the whole majority-votes thing, it obviously becomes a problem with the (not just poorly named but also poorly-categorized) "off-topic" set of reasons. Any and all of the canned off-topic reasons, whether appropriate or not, will be listed in the close notice regardless of which one gets the majority vote, simply because they're all "off-topic" reasons. [Case in point.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21910393/why-are-the-margins-of-adjoining-sections-not-collapsing)

Comment: The [question OP refers to at end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116662/differences-when-writing-code-for-arm-vs-x86) is not well-focused and has two questions in the body.  Looks like a good candidate for "Unclear What You Are Asking", "Too Broad" and perhaps the old "Too Localized".  He talks about code he needs to write.  *But what code?* It also has strong hints of being an A/B question related to cross-compiling.

Comment: Is there a better phrasing you're suggesting?

Comment: I am also seeing a rash of questions being closed as opinion when this is just not appropriate at all.  Often these questions are lacking some info to make them good questions (so it looks like people just go looking for a close reason), but what really needs to be done is the OP needs to be told how their question needs to be improved and the issue has nothing to do with opinion.  Here's [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25979573/when-to-use-jquery-load-method#comment40680915_25979573) I thought needed to be improved in other ways, but the issue was not about opinion at all.

Comment: @jfriend00 [As per this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260088/rename-primarily-opinion-based?noredirect=1#comment40261_260090) of mine, for a little while I tried to measure how common this actually was. I now think that what led me to start this conversation was an unusual streak of close votes, and that the actual problem is smaller than I thought. It may be a problem, but I no longer think it's worth pursuing. If you want to argue this claim further, I suggest you try it too. Maybe you'll end up with substantial evidence, in which case you'll be able to restart the debate.

Comment: @Veedrac - I've been seeing the problem a lot lately (several times a day in the small subset of questions I choose to participate in).  Usually, it's a somewhat poorly worded question to start with and, rather than ask the OP to clarify and given them a chance to do that (which is my standard approach), I think some set of people go trolling for a reason to vote to close immediately and for reasons I don't understand, they are picking on the opinion reason even if there are many possible good, non-opinion-based answers.  Why this is happening more lately, I don't know.

Comment: @jfriend00 Can you collect a little list of them for Meta to look at? It'd be interesting to see what the opinions are.

Comment: @Veedrac - I can start trying to keep track of what I see.  It is something I've been noticing a lot more in the last month.  What would I do with a list?

Comment: Just throw it on a Meta post with a few mentions to here, I guess. You could always make a long rambly rant to go with it if you feel like you should join the Meta tradition ;). If I agree with your judgement I might try and restart the debate from this post.

Comment: I think there's a core misunderstanding about what an "opinion-based question" is that should actually be closed. If you look at answers on SO, even great answers on SO, they is plenty of opinion involved (often intermixed with data/facts).  Every line of code in an answer is someone's opinion on how to best express that code as there is pretty much never a single way to code a solution.  So, many SO answers contain opinion. And, many useful and good questions are really asking for someone to explain some things and describe the opinion they draw from an educated understanding of those things.

Comment: Certainly, there are questions which can draw absolutely nothing but opinion and those should be targeted for closing.  But, there's a huge gray area between that and a question that is 100% factual and many of the questions in that gray area are good, useful questions that are beneficial to the community and that I think SO wants.  If SO really wanted no questions with any opinion in them, I think the volume would drop by 90%.  It is the giant gray area where the problem is.

Comment: @Veedrac - sorry, but I don't know my way around Meta.  What is "Meta post"?

Comment: @jfriend00 A question. [Example.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260088/1763356)

Comment: The question gets at my biggest complaint with SO. The community is reducing its usefulness by closing questions based on a very broad interpretation of opinion. Even after a question is closed, I've tried to edit the question so that it removes a call for opinion and then that isn't accepted because moderators felt it strayed from OP's question - which was closed due to an opinion request.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358221/shader-ide-suggestion-for-glsl-or-hlsl

Comment: @Andrew I would consider that close valid. See [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Comment: @veedra, so when someone needs software, do they have to migrate to the new software recs board?

Comment: @Andrew I believe that is the consensus, yes.

Answer (score 19):

[There are two types of subjective questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).  There are those that are asking for *opinions*, and there are those that are encouraging *expertise*.  Opinions are what we don't want here, expertise is what we *do* want here.

Changing the term "opinion" to "subjective" is making the close reason apply to the types of questions that we want to allow, while still having it apply to everything that we don't want it to apply to.

So no, we shouldn't make that change.

Comment: True, but then you agree that the problem is the same. I'll remove the specific suggestion, but the close reason does need to be renamed. For exactly the reason of this answer.

Comment: @Veedrac You haven't provided sufficient cause for me to belive that.  You have *one* example of a question improperly closed with this reason, and that questions should still be closed, just for a different reason.  When you have evidence of significant problems, then we can discuss solutions.

Comment: This seems to be the opinion of Robert Harvey too: I need evidence of questions actually getting closed. I'll try to compile a list over the next week or so, although there will be bias by the fact that if I'm right then *I'm* also going to be working more than the normal reviewer to keep them open.

Comment: I feel like "subjective" and "opinion-based" have the opposite connotations. There is such a thing as an expert opinion, but saying something is highly subjective suggests that everyone's opinion is more or less equal. I think "Too subjective" would be a good way of conveying the idea, but obviously my internal lexicon isn't normative.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689887/why-do-we-need-anaconda-when-we-have-pip/23690007) is another case of, in my opinion, a question asking for expertise that was closed as opinion based.

Comment: @Chuck Then your definitions of the words aren't in line with the accepted definitions.  A subjective question is one in which there isn't a single verifiable correct answer.  An opinion is a statement that has no basis in fact for its assertion.  An opinion based question is always subjective, but there can be subjective questions that will require answers to provide facts and evidence which indicates a probable answer, while still not necessarily being sufficient to assert that it is objective and irrefutably correct.  Even if a question is subjective, it should be supported by evidence.

Comment: Isn't _expertise_ just an _opinion_ from someone with more experience?

Comment: @MattK No, it's an opinion that is supported by facts and evidence, rather than a belief that should be accepted on faith, regardless of how experienced the person is.

Comment: Seems like the dictionary disagrees... "a written _opinion_ by an expert" and "expert _opinion_ or commentary". I don't think you can have an opinion that is based completely on facts and evidence. By definition it would cease to be an opinion (subjective) any more, and become fact (objective).

Comment: @MattK It's that "completely" in there that makes the difference.  A question is subjective, but still a quality question, when there is facts and evidence provided, but it is insufficient to, in and of itself, lead to an objective answer.  When evidence is combined with an opinion interpreting an incomplete set of facts, so long as there is sufficient evidence, it can fall onto the "good subjective" side rather than the "bad subjective" side.

Comment: Ah, so there are levels of subjectivity. How would you be able to determine if a question can produce a "good subjective" answer or a "bad subjective" answer?

Comment: @MattK I have given you a starting point, but if you are interested in a more in-depth explanation you should read the linked blog article titled, "Good Subjective, Bad Subjective". It, unsurprisingly, is an entire article that goes about defining what types of subjective questions we do and don't want on this site.  Interestingly, determining if a question is Good Subjective or Bad Subjective is itself subjective (although it is the good kind) because the world loves irony. There are metrics to which one can use to evaluate the quality of a subjective question, but they are not all objective.

Comment: Should [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25939324/what-are-the-benefits-of-logic-less-templates-vs-more-capabilities-in-the-templ) have been closed as opinion-based?  Sure doesn't seem so to me.  It was just asking what was the programming rationale behind "logic-less templates".  There exist good expertise-based answers for that question.  Whether "logic-less" templates are the best kind of templates is more of an opinion kind of question, but that isn't the focus here.  This was closed as opinion-based.  Seems part of the recent rash of "opinion-closers".

Comment: @jfriend00 That question seems like it's more "too broad" than too opinion based.  It's asking an extremely open ended question that is more or less asking for an entire explanation of [topic].  Questions of that format are almost always going to be too broad.  It does have a fair number of warning signs of an opinion based question, so I can understand what some people would use that reason, but "too broad" is the clearer, less ambiguous, and harder to fix problem, so I'd go with that reason.

Comment: @Servy - The programming rationale behind logic-less templates is a very specific question.  Why would that be too broad?  It can be answered based purely on expertise and can be answered with a bullet list of 2-N relevant points.  How is that either opinion-based or too broad?  Anyone who authored a logic-less template package, championed that design choices vs. the other choices or surveyed the available options and selected a logic-less design for its benefits would be more than qualified to offer these bullet points in a good answer.

Comment: @jfriend00 How is it specific?  You're asking to explain the entirety of a topic, without bounds.  What makes it *not* too broad?  It's opinion based in that the reasons you may want to use it can vary widely from the reasons someone else might (or might not) want to use it.  No answer can ever really be "enough"; it can never be conclusively "the" answer.  There's always something more to say, another area to discuss, another reason to add.

Comment: @jfriend00 The edit to your comment makes it pretty clear that you're *actively searching for people to give their opinions on the topic*.  That is exactly what we *don't* want to be doing here on SO.  We don't want to create a discussion in which everyone lists out their opinion on the matter and states why they like best about X.  You've only succeeded in convincing me that opinion based is actually very applicable given what you want out of the question.

Comment: @Servy - how would one ask a question on StackOverflow that would help them understand the benefits of logic-less templates then?  Is that just not a topic that can be discussed on StackOverflow?  There are certainly many expertise-based answers that could explain such benefits (assuming those benefits exist).  Most answers on StackOverflow involve some opinion.  The issue is whether it's mostly opinion being asked for and whether that's really the only possible answer, not whether opinion could be involved or not.

Comment: @jfriend00 SO is not the place to hold a discussion of a topic.  There are many thousands of places on the internet that you *can* go to hold an open ended discussion on a topic, but SO is not one of them.  Honestly I'm rather shocked that I actually need to explain that to someone who's been using the site for years and has thousands of posts.

Comment: @Servy - I'm not looking for a discussion.  I'm looking for some facts.  What are the benefits of logic-less templates vs. ones that allow more logic?

Comment: @jfriend00 And that's not the type of question that's appropriate here; a very broad, open ended question in which there really aren't concrete metrics for providing a conclusive answer.  That is effectively a discussion.  You stating that it's not a discussion doesn't make it not a discussion.

Comment: A question should be closed as primarily opinion-based when the only possible answers are opinions, not when answers that offer good facts and perhaps describe some logical reasoning using those facts can be offered.  If you think the only possible answers to the logic-less template question are entirely opinion, then apparently you don't understand either the issue or the question or the types of answers that could be provided.  An excellent answer could be provided with bullet points that most would easily consider it the "best answer" and not based on opinion.

Comment: A "benefit" is not a fact.  You can state a fact about [topic] and person A can think that it's a benefit and person B can think that it's a major flaw, and they can both be right.  Asking a question in which the fact itself is the answer isn't asking for opinions, asking a question in which the fact itself isn't the answer, but rather the person's opinion about the fact *is the answer* makes it an opinion based question.  You *aren't* asking for a list of facts about the topic, you're asking for *people's opinion* about the topic.

Comment: And if the question were to be re-worded so that it would just be asking for facts, then it would still be "too broad".  "Give me all of the facts about [thing]" isn't a reasonably scoped SO question.  You're not really doing anything to bound the possible facts that could be listed about [thing], making the question effectively unanswerable.

Comment: Geez - by your definition >80% of the questions on SO are opinion-based and should not be there.  For example, every line of code is someone opinion on how it should be written, not a fact.  I answer thousands of questions to offer "good design patterns" to solve problems.  Those are my opinions about the better way to solve the problem vs. other answers or vs. what the OP already has.  Get practical here for a moment.  You're way overboard on ruling out any possible use of opinion in providing an answer.

Comment: @Servy - Also "benefits" is not necessarily opinion.  Are benefits like "smaller" or "faster" or "supported by X foundation" or "runs on X, Y and Z platforms" or "contains feature Y" all opinions?

Comment: @jfriend00 Whether something is smaller, faster, runs on X platform, contains feature Y, etc. can be facts.  Whether or not they are beneficial is an opinion.  SO is designed to primarily support questions along the lines of "I have ___ problem, how can I solve it?"  An answer either solves that problem or it does not; there tends to be very little subjectivity when the question is good.  Whether it's the best way to solve that problem is subjective (and that's fine), but *that* it solves the problem rarely is.